# ObjectMapper writeValueAsString on 'null' vs 'NullNode.getInstance()'

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

Consider the following statements:

`String s1 = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(null);`

`String s2 = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(NullNode.getInstance());`

In both the cases, serialized values `s1` and `s2` would be `"null"` (in String format). Jackson, by default, serializes `null` objects without any exception.
What are the cases where we need to use `NullNode`, instead of directly serializing `null`?

Comment: that sould be a json string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"null"` here is a string, not the `null` value. This is what `writeValueAsString` does: it wrote a null value or a NullNode as a `"null"` string.

The `NullNode` is a special type in Jackson that denotes the `null` value. For example, reading the following JSON will deserialize into a `NullNode` (which is a singleton):

```
JsonNode readValue = new ObjectMapper().readValue(" { \"abc\" : null }", JsonNode.class);
JsonNode jsonNode = readValue.get("abc"); // will return a NullNode
assertTrue(jsonNode == NullNode.getInstance());
```